# Aurelia: During a Router's Pipeline Step, how do I bind a variable to that router?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'd like to pass the user, found during the `AuthorizeStep` to either the `App class` and then to the `home module`.

Here's what I have:

```
export class App {
    configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep); 
        config.map([
            {route: ['', ':filter'], name: "", moduleId: 'welcome'}
            {route: 'home', name: "home", moduleId: 'home' auth:true}
        ]);
        this.router = router;
    }
}

class AuthorizeStep {
    run(routingContext, next) {
        if (routingContext.nextInstructions.some(i => i.config.auth)) {
            this.client.get('auth/login')
                .then(response => {
                    this.user = response.content;
                });
        }
        return next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my app I created a class called AuthContext with currentUser property. You can inject it in the constructor for the AuthorizeStep and then inject it in any other models that need it. Something like...

```
import {AuthContext} from './auth-context';

export class App {
    static inject() { return [AuthContext];}

    constructor(authcontext){
        this.authContext = authcontext;
    }

    configureRouter(config, router) {
         config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep); 
         config.map([
            {route: ['', ':filter'], name: "", moduleId: 'welcome'}
            {route: 'home', name: "home", moduleId: 'home' auth:true}
        ]);
        this.router = router;
    }
}

class AuthorizeStep {
    static inject() { return [AuthContext];}

    constructor(authcontext){
        this.authContext = authcontext;
    }
    run(routingContext, next) {
        if (routingContext.nextInstructions.some(i => i.config.auth)) {
            this.client.get('auth/login')
                .then(response => {
                    this.authcontext.user = response.content;
                });
        }
        return next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you wire this up to a child router? I am getting Error: Pipeline steps can only be added to the root router.

Comment: No. "Aurelia has two router classes, AppRouter and Router. AppRouter extends the Router class and is the main application router. Router is used for any child routers including nested child routers. One of the main differences between the two is pipelines are only allowed on the AppRouter and not any child routers." http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/8

Answer (score 6):

I have been doing something similar, but I found that I can't rely on the `authcontext` being populated in other viewmodels by the time the viewmodel is being attached. Returning the promise returned by the `get` and then returning `next()` within the resolution of the `get` seems to solve that, the idea being to not proceed to the next pipeline step until this one has resolved. Applying that to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31430356/254603) from @JamesCarters, I'd get the following (untested) code:

```
class AuthorizeStep {
    static inject() { return [AuthContext];}

    constructor(authcontext){
        this.authContext = authcontext;
    }
    run(routingContext, next) {
        if (routingContext.nextInstructions.some(i => i.config.auth)) {
            return this.client.get('auth/login')
                .then(response => {
                    this.authcontext.user = response.content;
                    return next();
                });
        }
        else {
            return next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While the accepted answer does address the question, I believe this is what most people should be doing. If you have an instruction dependent on authorization, certainly want to make sure you authorization is complete before you navigate to that instruction!