# Aurelia js authorization

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, aurelia

I’m new to Aurelia, so my question is what is guidance for using Aurelia in multi user environment. Windows authentication with authorization by a role? Does anyone have sample code, maybe with asp mvc as a host?

Comment: are you asking for how to build an authorisation mechanism?

Comment: That or seeing if anything available out of the box. Or maybe someone built one already and willing to share it. Basically any information about the subject is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a simple authorisation workflow:

App Structure:

```
/src
 main.js
 -app
   -app.html -- app root component for logged users
   -app.js -- app root component for logged users
   -nav-bar.html
   -nav-bar.js
 -login
   -login.js -- app root component for unlogged users
   -login.html -- app root component for unlogged users
   -user-password.html -- route with user/password fields.
   -user-password.js -- route with user/password fields.
   -forgot-password.html
   -forgot-password.js
```

**MAIN.JS:**

```
export function(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  //initialise
  aurelia.start().then(a => {
    let rootComponent = isLoggedIn() ? 'app/app' : 'login/login';
    a.setRoot(rootComponent, document.body);
  });
});

function isLoggedIn() {
  //do your magic here
  //check if the current user has a valid authorisation token
}
```

**APP.HTML:**

```
<template>
  <!-- THIS IS WHERE YOU APP WILL BE RENDERED (if the user is logged) -->
  <nav-bar></nav-bar>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

**LOGIN.HTML:**

```
<template>
  <!-- THIS IS WHERE YOU APP WILL BE RENDERED (if the user is not logged) -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

**LOGIN.JS:**

```
export class Login {

configureRouter(config, router) {
  config.map([
    { route: '', name: 'user-password', moduleId: './user-password', title: 'Sign In' },
    { route: 'forgot-password', name: 'forgot-password', moduleId: './forgot-password', title: 'Forgot Password?' }
  ]);
  config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
    //check instruction.fragment
    return './user-password';
  });

  this.router = router;
}

}
```

**USER-PASSWORD.HTML**

```
<template>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="password">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</template>
```

**USER-PASSWORD.JS**

```
export class UserPassword {

  login() {
    //check if the user and password are valid
    //redirect to the app root component
    //import and inject { Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
    this.aurelia.setRoot('app/app');
  }
}
```

If something is not clear enough, just ask me!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is pretty good, but how would I handle a different ui elements ( router-view, etc.)  based on user role? An admin should have a different menu options from a regular authenticated user.

Comment: There's a lot of possibilities. You could create a web component to render the menu options. That component should identify which options should be shown to current user.  
Or perhaps you could create a totally different root component for the admins.

Comment: You should also configure your router to use an authorisation pipeline. Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425138/aurelia-during-a-routers-pipeline-step-how-do-i-bind-a-variable-to-that-route

Answer (score 0):

There is an isomorphic authorization library which is called [CASL](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/) . You can read about its integration in Aurelia app on medium https://medium.com/@sergiy.stotskiy/casl-based-authorization-in-aurelia-app-3e44c0fe1703

Answer (score 0):

There is a library `CASL` which I wrote to handle authorization logic in JavaScript. Also you can find [a sample application of integration CASL and Aurelia](https://github.com/stalniy/casl-aurelia-example) on my github and [related article on Medium](https://medium.com/@sergiy.stotskiy/casl-based-authorization-in-aurelia-app-3e44c0fe1703).

Hope this will be helpful!